# Is "in what little time he had" a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

For example:

"It is impressive how he did what he did, specially **in what little time he had**"

Is the sentence structure and grammar correct?

Comment: Other than *especially* instead of *specially*, why not? Proofreading without citing the source of concern is off-topic.

Comment: **what** can act as a determiner. It could say "in *the* little time he had".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.  [There are many examples out there](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in%20what%20little%20time%22), for instance

> [...doing everything they could do in what little time they had...](https://books.google.com/books?id=hOOhCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&dq=%22in%20what%20little%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-9aGVoe_NAhWIHR4KHeBvA54Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20what%20little%20time%22&f=false)

> [It continues to show us that whatever we achieve in what little time we have is but a flawed, deficient proxy...](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZnFTDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&dq=%22in%20what%20little%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-9aGVoe_NAhWIHR4KHeBvA54Q6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22in%20what%20little%20time%22&f=false)

> [Most authors have written their chapters in what little time they had left over from war research.](https://books.google.com/books?id=8XHt_t33rGIC&pg=PR9&dq=%22in%20what%20little%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj10sfuoe_NAhUC1h4KHTMLCdY4ChDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=%22in%20what%20little%20time%22&f=false)

One minor correction - "in what little time he had" is a phrase, not a sentence, since it can only be used to modify something else.